# Delete row function from table in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I run the program and add student to the list, then I delete this studentlist row. Then When I add new student the studentlist show me both deleted row and new inserted row? How can I solve this?

```
function renderStudentList() {
  tableBody.innerHTML = "";
  studentList.map((student) => {
    const studentRow = `
            <tr>
                <td>${student.id}</td>
                <td>${student.name}</td>
                <td>${student.surname}</td>
                <td>${student.birthday}</td>
                <td>${student.age}</td>
                <td>${student.gender === "M" ? "Male" : "Female"}</td>
                <td>
                    <img id="delete" src="./icons/delete.svg" alt="delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)">
                    <img id="edit" src="./icons/edit.svg" alt="edit" >
                </td>
            </tr>
        `;
    tableBody.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", studentRow);
  });
}

addStudentBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const newStudent = {
    id: generateId(),
    name: document.getElementById("name").value,
    surname: document.getElementById("surname").value,
    birthday: document.getElementById("birthday").value,
    age: document.getElementById("age").value,
    gender: document.getElementById("genderM").checked ? "M" : "F",
  };
  if (isDataValid(newStudent)) {
    document.getElementById("student-form").reset();
    studentList.push(newStudent);
    renderStudentList();
  } else {
    console.log("PLEASE FILL THE DATA");
  }
});

function deleteRow(r) {
  var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  document.getElementById("table-body").deleteRow(i - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are removing the row from the DOM by calling `deleteRow(i - 1)` but not from the actual list inside `studentList`, that's why next time you call `renderStudentList()`, what you have deleted shows up.

An easy way to overcome this and that would simplify your code is to to first change `renderStudentList()` so each row gets an id, like so:

```
function renderStudentList() {
  tableBody.innerHTML = "";
  studentList.map((student) => {
    const studentRow = `
      <tr id="${student.id}">
        <td>${student.id}</td>
        <td>${student.name}</td>
        <td>${student.surname}</td>
        <td>${student.birthday}</td>
        <td>${student.age}</td>
        <td>${student.gender === "M" ? "Male" : "Female"}</td>
        <td>
          <img id="delete" src="./icons/delete.svg" alt="delete" onclick="deleteRow(${student.id})" />
          <img id="edit" src="./icons/edit.svg" alt="edit" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    `;
    tableBody.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", studentRow);
  });
}
```

And `deleteRwo` as below, so it removes the element from the DOM as well as from the list, by using the id that he gets while generating the template littoral:

```
function deleteRow(id) {
  studentList = studentList.filter(student => student.id !== id);
  document.getElementById(`${id}`).remove();
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. it gives error: student isn't defined onclick img

Comment: I made a mistake, take my new version of `renderStudentList()`. I just edited it. Also I wanna know, `generateId()` returns a string, right?

Comment: it returns number:                                                                                                                                   function generateId() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
}

Comment: Okay, try my last edits of the two functions and let me know.

Comment: Hi @Javascript, is your problem solved?